# ActiveRecord: Filtering duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Given this table:

```
Users
| id | name  | active |
| 1  | bob   | true   |
| 2  | bob   | false  |
| 3  | alice | false  |
```

How can i query this table using ActiveRecord (Rails 4.2, PostgreSQL), if the resulting relation should

- have all attributes populated
- not contain duplicate names
- prefer active records in favor to inactive ones
- be capable of calling .count, where count returns an integer
- remain an ActiveRecord::Relation

The correct result set should look like this:

```
Users
| id | name  | active |
| 1  | bob   | true   |
| 3  | alice | false  |
```

What i tried so far:

```
# Works as for the result set, but raises when calling .count
User.select('DISTINCT ON (users.name) *')
    .order(users.name, users.active DESC')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
User.select('DISTINCT name').order('name, active DESC').count
```

Comment: While count works, this query fails on accessing elements from the relation, as 'for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list'

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "elements from relation"?

Comment: `User.select('DISTINCT name').order('name, active DESC').first`

Comment: It returns the first record just tried it, still don't see the problem?

Comment: I should have mentioned i'm using Postgres, the error mentioned above doesn't happen on SQLITE for example. Anyway, your suggestion does not populate all columns:
`> User.select('DISTINCT name').order('name, active DESC').first`
`=> #<User id: nil, name: "alice">`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
User.where.not(name: nil).where.not(active: nil)
```

This returns all users with a populated name and active boolean (ids will always be populated)

Then on that we call

```
.uniq_by(:name)
```

This gives us only records with a unique name
And finally

```
.sort_by { |a| a.active ? 1 : 0 }
```

Puts records with active: true at the start. So the method is:

```
User.where.not(name: nil).where.not(active: nil).uniq_by(:name).sort_by { |a| a.active ? 1 : 0 }
```

On this query we can call count to get the number of objects.

---

EDIT:

To keep as AR change uniq_by to uniq:

```
User.where.not(name: nil).where.not(active: nil).uniq(name).sort_by { |a| a.active ? 1 : 0 }
```

Comment: Using uniq_by would require the Relation to be converted into an Array, while i need it to remain a relation. Updated my question.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: If i don't miss anything, uniq is an alias for distinct, which requires a .select to be present (otherwise it would result in `SELECT DISTINCT users.*`). Also, sort_by converts to Array

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using PostgreSQL, you can use [`DISTINCT ON`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT).  Here's the SQL:

```
select distinct on (name) * from users order by name, active desc
```

And in Active Record:

```
>> User.order(name: :desc, active: :desc).select("distinct on (name) *")
  User Load (2.5ms)  SELECT  distinct on (name) * FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."name" DESC, "users"."active" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 2, name: "bob", active: true, created_at: "2017-09-15 03:58:23", updated_at: "2017-09-15 03:58:23">, #<User id: 3, name: "alice", active: false, created_at: "2017-09-15 03:58:35", updated_at: "2017-09-15 03:58:35">]>
```

Comment: That's what i already tried, unfortunately i can't call .count on that relation.

Comment: You're right, I missed that when reading the question, my bad.  And while you can call `User.count_by_sql(User.order(name: :desc, active: :desc).select("distinct on (name) *"))`, that is two queries and doesn't satisfy the original question either.